# Convert Play Framework java Promise to Play Framework Scala Promise

Tags: java, scala, playframework, promise

I am currently building a Scala play framework app which uses a library that return results as F.Promise (Java Promise). Is there a way to convert F.Promises (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html) into Scala Promises or get the wrapped Scala Future out of the F.Promise?

The only way I see so far is getting the F.Promise but that is a blocking operation and I would like to continue working asynchronous.

The way descriped in the first answer led me to this code. Unfortunately I dont know how to define this F.Function correctly. The code does not compile.

Answer:
So, I finally found out that the F.Promise has a method called wrapped(). And this method gives you a Scala Future back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the class F.Promise (java.play) has a method called `wrapped()` which returns the `scala.concurrente.Future` that is wrapped by the Promise. So all you have to do is calling wrapped on the F.Promise.

```
val promise: F.Promise[T] = getPromise()
val future : Future[T] = promise.wrapped()
```

Comment: It would be great if you could go into a little more detail here, explaining what you did.

Comment: Added some more explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, since there is no 'standard' for promises or futures in that ecosystem, you'd have to do it manually. There is no concept of 'assimilation' between play promises and scala futures.

Basically, we treat a `F.Promise` like we'd treat a callback, we convert it to a scala Future by creating a Promise (which, confusingly in scala means "that which creates a Future"). Here is a description of how this works rather than code since I think that would explain the rationale better:

- Create a new `Promise[T]` - p
- Call `.map` on the `F.Promise` you have, in the `F.Function` passed to it, call `p success` with the value of the promise - effectively resolving the promise.
- Similarly - call `.recover` on the promise and inside its handler call `p failure` with the failure reason.
- Return `p.future`, which is a future representing the value `p` is resolved with - since we mirrored both the success and failure channels this will work.

This is not unlike how you would convert anything else to a scala Future. Converting in the other direction works similarly.

Comment: Iam not sure if I can follow you completly but I will try to put it into code. Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: @MeiSign my aim is for you to understand what we're doing and why - I'm experimenting with answering with the steps to the solution rather than the solution itself because I think it might be more productive - if you're stuck let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: I think I understand your idea but I am struggling with passing the F.Function to the java map function. Can you help me with that part? Here is what I have so far: http://www.gist.github.com/MeiSign/ef70b73ae8433a8c53cd

Comment: push because I think u got no comment notification due to my deleted first comment